# Cant edit custom post type in WordPress dashboard

Tags: php, html, css, wordpress

i'm working with a WordPress site developed by someone else , when i login to dashboard and try to edit  any custom post  type  that  takes me  to blank page for example there is a post type news and when i press edit button against any news item this is url

```
site.com/wp-admin/post.php?post=795&action=edit
```

And there is a blank page under it , i can edit posts and pages but not custom post types , this site is done by some one else so really don't know about problem can someone help me normally why blank page comes in WordPress  while editing  something.  if i do quick edit that is also available and change can be made through that ,

And one more thing if i want to change values of CPT from phpmyadmin (db)directly in which table should i look for custom post types

Comment: Either check the root instalation folder for error log, or go to wp-config.php and set `define('WP_DEBUG', true);`. 
And don't try to change anything in database directly. You're very likely to break the whole thing.

Answer (score 2):

Usually, a blank page means a code error. Maybe that's why you can't edit the post.

Custom Posts are in wp_posts as all other posts, pages, attachments, etc.
Posts metas are in wp_postmeta

Hope that helps.